# Get registry import result

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, frameworks, registry

I am using the command "regedit /s something.reg" to import .reg file to system registry. However, is there anyway to get the result of the process without having any of Regedit's message boxes pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reg import` command instead.  It's a command-line tool, so there are no pop-ups.  It returns `0` for success and `1` for failure.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, how can I get that return value returned by the cmd in my program? (Winforms + C#)

Comment: Through Process.Start(). Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: That's okay.  Try `Process.ExitCode`

Comment: So immediately after the reg import command, Process.ExitCode will be set to the appropriate value?

Comment: No, only after Process.WaitForExit().

Comment: BTW it seems that the ExitCode is always 0 regardless of whether the imported registry command is correct or not.